# how to generate today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format '%Y-%m-%d' using Python3

Tags: python, datetime

it is possible to generate YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 with the below code.  However, this is pretty ugly.

Is there a more elegant way?

Thanks

```
# calculate current date in format YYYY-MM-DD (ugly hack)
strToday = str(datetime.datetime.today()).split()[0]
dateToday = datetime.datetime.strptime(strToday, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: What about it is ugly?

Comment: That looks fine? You could always use `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`. Then you only need `datetime` instead of `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: I disagree with the comments above: formatting into a string just to parse it back out is indeed an ugly hack and a bad idea. The `datetime` constructor can take arbitrary fields, or you can use the `replace()` method to replace arbitrary fields, either of which are better than working with strings like this.

Comment: Use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) instead, `datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: "Today's date", as in the question title, is ambiguous. Do you want to end up with a datetime object or with a string?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input.  The code has been modified but still requires two steps.  The hope was to accomplish this on one line.

```
# calculate current date in format YYYY-MM-DD 
strToday = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dateToday = datetime.strptime(strToday, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Below demonstrates the data type conversion requirement for the above method.

```
## this approaches results to a string data type
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> print(date)
'2018-11-23'
>>> print(type(date))
<class 'str'>

## second step is still required to convert to datetime data type
>>> dateobject = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> print(type (dateobject))
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> print(str(dateobject))
2018-11-23 00:00:00
```